# Is there any risk my web app become slow cause too many threads in the bg?

Tags: python-3.x, web, pythonanywhere

I have a web application hosted on pythonanywhere and I have a doubt that if I have too many threads running in the background at the same time (because too many users sending requests), my web application will slow down or even crash.

Is there any chance of this happening? If so, which is the way to handle thousands of simultaneous threads properly?

This is what "a one" thread does: search links in google search engine and then web scrape them. But a user can start up to 6 threads executing the same, so imagine having thousands of users.

I'm using **'import threading'** module.

If you need to ask something about my code, ask freely.

Pd. I know this isn´t a directly code question, but still hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Can a site crash due to excessive thread counts? Sure. You can use non-thread based parallelism (e.g. `asyncio`, greenlets, etc.) to avoid this issue, or use something like `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` instead of raw threads to cap the number of threads in operation (though that of course means that if you have more requests being serviced than threads, new connections block until a worker becomes free). Beyond that, this is an essentially unanswerable question.

Comment: So if i readapat my code to asyncio or greenlets, the "site crash due to excessive thread counts" wont be a problem anymore?

Comment: Sure, but it could still run out of *other* resources. Excessive open file handles, excessive memory use, etc. There are fundamental trade-offs to be made between maximum simultaneous requests, responsiveness, etc. There's no one answer here; website optimization is a *huge* topic. Most Python web frameworks offer one or more approaches to improving this. For example, Tornado is specifically marketed for being "`asyncio` before `asyncio` even existed", theoretically scaling to tens of thousands of connections using asyncio. The topic is well beyond what Stack Overflow can handle.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend doing your own research on high performance Python web framework options, rather than trying to write your own web server from scratch. A lot of the work has been done for you if you're willing to learn the framework.

Comment: Threading is currently not supported in web apps on PythonAnywhere.  Also, there's a 5 min timout set on requests.  You may have a look in your server/error logs to check what's happening there.  As a workaround you may want to consider using [Always-on task feature](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AlwaysOnTasks/).